# Adding factory getting Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to add a simple factory and getting error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=subfactoryProvider%20%3C-%20subfactory%20%3C-%20authService%20%3C-%20AuthorizationInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile
```

I have added a script tag:

```
<script src="app/subfactory.js"></script>
```

The subfactory is defined as follows:

```
(function () {
    //'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('subfactory', subfactory);

    function subfactory() {

        var subValue = {};
        return {
            set: set,
            get: get
        };

        function get() {
            return subValue;
        }

        function set(value) {
            subValue = value;
        }
    }

});
```

It is used in authService:

```
(function () {
    //'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('authService', authService);

    authService.$inject = ['subfactory'];

    function authService(subfactory) {

       // removed code for brevity

        mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                var idToken = user.id_token;
                var dataIdToken = getDataFromToken(idToken);
                subfactory.set(dataIdToken.sub);
            } else {
                //console.log("User not logged in");
            }
        });
```

I also have AuthorizationInterceptor that calls authService:

```
app.factory("AuthorizationInterceptor", ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$window', 'authService', function ($q, $injector, $rootScope, $window, authService) {
```

Please, How can I resolve this error?

Edit:

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/authService.js"></script>
<script src="app/subfactory.js"></script>
```

`app.factory("AuthorizationInterceptor"...` is defined in `app.js`

The error message is the only message in the F12 console.

Comment: What is the order in which your are defining those factories and what is this `app` variable that your are creating the `AuthorizationInterceptor` in ?

Comment: If you see this error this means that either subfactory.js wasn't loaded or it was loaded before the file in which `app` module is defined (and there should be another error that says that).

Answer (score 2):

Try flipping the order of your declaration files like follows :

```
// only define your module here
<script src="app/app.js"></script>

// define your factories
<script src="app/subfactory.js"></script>
<script src="app/authService.js"></script>

// define your authorization factory here just like the previous two
<script src="app/Authorization.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I get - `Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/nomod?p0=app` - then the original error

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, would you also please thumb it up ?

Comment: Actually I still have issue with splitting it out - now getting  [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=subfactoryProvider%20%3C-%20subfactory%20%3C-%20authService%20%3C-%20AuthorizationInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile

Comment: So the same error you are getting in the beginning ?

Comment: Actually I have just managed to get it working - added to `app.js` before the `app.factory("AuthorizationInterceptor"...` sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sure, no worries.

Comment: It would appear the checkmark is gone, is there a reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Can not add it as comment. So adding an answer here. You need to change the order of file declaration . In your case error is because you have `authService.js` before `subfactory.js`. `authService.js` searches for its dependency and do not find it as `subfactory.js` yet not added.

```
 <script src="app/app.js"></script>// If it main file whre angular module is created
<script src="app/subfactory.js"></script>
<script src="app/authService.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I get - `Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/nomod?p0=app` - then the original error

Comment: if app.js is main file whre angular module is defined than put it to top